# Android Studio Wifi-Ap setup gives error: App not allowed to read or update stored WiFi Ap config

Tags: android, android-permissions, hotspot

I was creating an app that will create and enable wifi hotspot of my mobile using the given credential

```
public static boolean setHotspotName(String ssid, String pass, Context context) {
    try {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Method getConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager);

        wifiConfig.SSID = ssid;

        Method setConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration", WifiConfiguration.class);
        setConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfig);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

getting this error

```
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: App not allowed to read 
or update stored WiFi Ap config (uid = 10492)
```

Comment: all permission I've given

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG"/>`

Comment: As of Android Oreo (26), a new permission check was added to the service implementation of the getWifiApConfiguration() method.

Comment: It's possible modify the configuration? i try to do everything but all the time i got the same answer "app not allowed to read or update stored Wifi Ap ..."

Comment: @souravjana did you figure this out ?

Comment: the only thing available so far is `wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled")`

Comment: @Ultimo_m so as of now we cannot modify hotspot configuration such as ssid and password?

Comment: @CharlesSemaan not anymore to my knowledge, google is restricting on latest android even reading hotspot name

Comment: @CharlesSemaan check this answer how to create your wifi hotspot if you need that https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996578/2736039

Answer (score 0):

must add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
and add platform.keystore create by system level –

[Changing Android hotspot settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392277/changing-android-hotspot-settings)

Snippet from framework AndroidManifest.xml

Not for use by third-party applications. -->

This means that your application needs to be signed by the platform key or be privileged to use this API.

Comment: must add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
and add platform.keystore create by system level

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this permission in the manifest :

```
</permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: This solution is not working on Android 10.